# Print the graphical representation of a control character in C

Tags: c, printing, char, controls, ascii

Is there a function that prints the graphical representation of a control character in C? For example "NULL" for 0, "DEL" for 127 and so on.
thanks

Comment: FYI, ASCII 0 is `NUL`, not `NULL`.

Comment: the easiest way to make the conversion from one byte to the accepted meaning of that byte is by creating the 256 array of pointers: static char * myTable[] = { "num"; ..... 'Del" .... };  and then accessing the table, using a byte as the index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no standard function for this, but you can easily create your own array/string mapping them. Or you could simply add a constant to map them into the unicode range for pictorial representations of the ASCII control characters.